# Simplify my function to postgres sql query

Tags: postgresql, function, postgis, plpgsql

Can I make this function simple, using only sql in Postgres? *(without delete, forget it)
I need only select and insert queries.*

I have tried with "with recursive"  no success.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mt_CriarRotaExecutada(id_rota integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    searchsql text := '';
    searchsqlId text := '';
    var_match RECORD;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('delete from rota_executada where id_rota = ' || CAST( id_rota As text));
    searchsql := 'select (ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom as the_geom,
                         id_destino 
                  from (select id, the_geom, id_destino 
                        from rota_data 
                        where num =' || CAST( id_rota As text) || 
                        ' order by id) a';

    FOR var_match IN EXECUTE(searchsql) 
    LOOP

        EXECUTE 'insert into rota_executada(id_rota, id_rua, id_destino, the_geom, visitado) 
                 select $1, id, $3, $2,  $4 
                 from ruas r 
                 ORDER BY r.the_geom <#> $2 
                 LIMIT 1' 
        USING id_rota, var_match.the_geom, var_match.id_destino, 'N';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thanks.

Comment: what operator is `<#>`  ?

Comment: Distance from one point to other. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: what is the difference with `<->` ?

Comment: You dont need execute for delete just `DELETE from rota_executada where id_rota = id_rota::text;`

Comment: In my experience with `<->` you cant do `LIMIT 1` because not always return the closest, you have to do `LIMIT 100` then sort and then `LIMIT 1`

Comment: <-> distance from A to B and <#> distance from A bounding box  to B bounding box

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `EXECUTE` just do the sql statement

```
DELETE from rota_executada where id_rota = id_rota::text;
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO rota_executada(id_rota, id_rua, id_destino, the_geom, visitado) 
   SELECT id_rota, id, var_match.id_destino, var_match.the_geom,  'N'
   FROM ruas r 
   ORDER BY r.the_geom <#> var_match.the_geom
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Tip: Dont make sense some places `id_rota` is integer and other is text. standarize your datatype to avoid bugs and mistakes

Comment: But, and the -- ST_DumpPoints(the_geom) select? I can't loose the st_dumppoints order

Comment: I didnt remove the `FOR var_match IN EXECUTE(searchsql) ` I just change the other two execute

Comment: I think don't explain it correctly. I want to simplify the function to a simple query. If possible. (forget delete)

Comment: You can simplify, but you will have to calculate all the distances and performace will be much worst. I think this is the best way already because the `LIMIT 1`  with the index make it very fast